# Transcribing a design to HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css

I've searched for ways to mask pictures using css and I found about `clip-path` I can successfully cut the image the way I want in the picture but my main problem right now is how I would just "push" all that text to the right side, should I use grids? Or can I do it purely with CSS using stuff like float?

Tried using float but it didn't end well with the other paragraphs

[image: Design with guides].

Comment: FYI, clip-path doesn't have wide-reaching browser support. It would be better to pull off the diagonal mask using a div layer which is rotated 45 degrees. For your text alignment, it's better for you to explore flexbox first. Earlier you mentioned frameworks; you should save that learning for the future, for now focus on fundamental HTML/CSS.

Comment: @MarsAndBack You don't need a diagonal mask. Just use background gradient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily achieve this considering multiple background layer then you can adjust the content easily to match the background:

```css
body {
  margin:0;
  height:100vh;
  background:
    linear-gradient(to bottom right, transparent 49%,red 50%)calc(100% - 200px) 0/100px 100%,
    linear-gradient(red,red) right/200px 100%,
    url(https://picsum.photos/1000/800?image=1069) center/cover;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

.box {
  width:200px;
  height:100%;
  margin-left:auto;
  padding:20px;
  text-align:center;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <h1>title</h1>
  <p>some content here</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there any way I can make the gradient look more like a straight up parallelogram instead of this half rectangle? I tried messing with all the parameters but can't seem to get it right. Here's what I'm talking about `polygon(25% 0, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);`

Comment: @KayleMeta check the update, simply adjust the 50vh in the code using any value (I replace it with 200px) .. is this what you want?